# Skipping "na" values when reading from csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

I am reading a list of values from a csv file into another list, and then calculating the mean of those values in the new list. The only issue is that some of the values in that list are simply the string "na" where no data was collected. If I want to skip over these "na" values, is it as simple as writing an if statement such as:

```
    if soil_anom=='na':
        pass
    else:
        SA.append(float(soil_anom))
```

I then have a numpy function to quickly calculate the mean of SA.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you're reading the csv in then yes; its that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the csv.DictReader(). Once read, you can traverse through the dict to replace the na with 0.

```
csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in csvReader:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) for reading the file. It possibly converts `"na"` to `NaN` automatically, or if not, you can tweak its behaviour with the optional *missing_values* and *filling_values* arguments.

Then you can calculate the mean of the resulting array with [`numpy.nanmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html), which ignores all `NaN`s.